# how to create check box and display it in templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, checkbox, django-forms

forms.py is

```
class ShowlivereportForm(forms.Form):
    livereport = forms.BooleanField()
```

How to create django check box

I dont't know how to create a template for showing the check box,can any one give me with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use django's automatic `as_p` function in templates, or you can write your template manually (to have more control on it's attributes).

For automatic you need this in your template:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

For manual you should use something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="livereport" name="livereport" {% if form.livereport.value %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
<label for="livereport">Show live report</label>
```

Comment: i did with "{{ form.as_p }}" it is not rendering the output

Comment: @user2086641 It works if you pass `form` as an argument of `render` function. Have a look at this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ and check the examples.

Comment: will go through that and implement